# Order by title Child Pages displayed in a Parent Page

Tags: php

I am using the code bellow to display a list of Child Pages on a Parent Page.
I want to order the displayed list by Alphabetical order. How can I achieve this?

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() { 
 
    global $post; 
 
    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
 
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
    else
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );
 
    if ( $childpages ) {
 
        $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
    }
 
    return $string;
 
}
 
add_shortcode('wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages');
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation of [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/). You can use the argument `sort_column` to specify the ordering. Use `sort_column=post_title` to list the pages alphabetically.

So your query for the child pages will become something like this:

```
$childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=post_title&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
```